# Is it possible to display information about the size of each local variable?

Tags: linux, gcc, local-variables, objdump

I want to find out if any too big non-static local variables are declared and used by some software developer in our team. Are there any GCC options and/or `objdump` parameters or something to produce and show information about local variables and their sizes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could use GCC's `-Wstack-usage` or `-Wframe-larger-than` to [warn on too big stack frames](https://www.flamingspork.com/blog/2014/05/25/caring-about-stack-usage/)?

Comment: That's great. While -Wstack-usage doesn't work in my compiler, -Wframe-larger-than works perfectly.